# How to delete or clear all the messages from the POSIX message queue in c?

Tags: c, linux, posix, ipc, message-queue

I want to delete all the messages from the POSIX message queue. I searched on the internet but I didn't find any way to do it instead I found the way to delete the message queue itself but that's not my case I actually want to clear all the pending messages from the message queue.

I was reading the man page in which I found `mq_setattr` API which is used to control the parameter for the message queue. I was just wondering if I set the value of `mq_curmsgs` to 0 by using `mq_setattr`, would it clear the pending messages from the queue?

Any help in this regard will be appreciated

Comment: Also from the man pages for mq_setattr: The only attribute that can be modified is the setting of the O_NONBLOCK flag in mq_flags.  The other fields in newattr  are  ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to clear a message queue is to `mq_receive` all messages but not process them.

---

[`man mq_setattr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_setattr.3.html):

> The only attribute that can be modified is the setting of the O_NONBLOCK flag in mq_flags.

Comment: Oh yes understood, we can process the messages in a while loop and once queue becomes empty we can break the while loop. Am I in the right direction?

Comment: @vivek Note that you may like to set that `O_NONBLOCK`, so that when the queue has been drained your `while` loop doesn't block in `mq_receive` but rather fails with `EAGAIN`.

Comment: yes got it. I'll take care of that. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The following pseudocode worked for me.

```
 struct mq_attr attr;
 mq = mq_open( .... ); // Create message queue.
 
 if( mq_getattr(mq, &attr) == 0 ){
    while(attr.mq_curmsgs) {
      printf("Clearing pending message # %d from the queue", (int)attr.mq_curmsgs);
      mq_receive(mq, .....);
      attr.mq_curmsg--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).